# Regex works for JS but not for PHP

Tags: php, regex

I would like to validate a phone number.

In JavaScript I tried it with `/^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9x]*$/` and it works great.

The same Regex I have used for PHP ...

```
if (preg_match("/^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9x]*$/", $_POST['phone'])) { ... }
```

but that doesn't work and returns:

> Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier '0'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Escape the delimiter, `/` char (see `/0` in your regex). As per the accepted answer, this case is *When you use the delimiter inside the pattern without escaping it.*

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew works great, thank you so much!!